# Using NDSolve for 4 coupled nonlinear PDEs

Tags: differential-equations

I tried to solve the following coupled PDEs using NDSolve but failed.

```
η = 1.61;(*Refractive index*)
c = 3 10^8;(*m/s, Speed of light*)
ℏ = 1.05 10^-34;(*J/s, Planck constant in radian*)
λ = 590 10^-9;(*m,Wavelength of optical pumping*)
ω = 2 π (c/λ);(*rad/s,Frequency of optical pumping in radian*)
B = 3.87 10^21;(*J^-1s^-2m^3,Einstein B coefficient*)
Φisc = 0.625;(*ISC yield*)
τF = 9 10^-9;(*s,fluorescence lifetime*)

pde = {D[ρ1[z, t], t] == -(η B 0.5 /c) Ibar[z, t] ρ1[z, t] + ((η B 0.5 /c) Ibar[z, t] + (1 - Φisc)/τF) ρ2[z, t],

   D[ρ2[z, t], t] == (η B 0.5 /c) Ibar[z, t] ρ1[z, t] - ((η B 0.5 /c) Ibar[z,t] + 1/τF) ρ2[z, t],

   D[ρ3[z, t], t] == Φisc/τF ρ2[z, t],

   D[Ibar[z, t], z] + η/c D[Ibar[z, t], t] == ((-ρ1[z, t] + ρ2[z, t]) η ℏ ω B 0.5 /c) Ibar[z, t],

   ρ1[z, 0] == 10^16, 
   ρ2[z, 0] == ρ3[z, 0] == 0, 
   Ibar[0, t] == 10^16};

sol = NDSolve[pde, {ρ1, ρ2, ρ3, Ibar}, {z, 0, 4 10^-3}, {t, 0, 2 10^-6}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}]
```

The warnings are about the initial and boundary conditions although I thought I've provided all known initial and boundary conditions.

Any comments are appreciated!

Comment: What do you try to solve?  Numbers in your model are to high for numerical method.

Comment: @AlexTrounev This is a model for calculating how many and how far optical photons can penetrate a sample containing dye molecules. The numbers of optical photons and dye molecules are indeed quite large (10^16 or even more). I adopted this model from a literature of which the authors successfully got numerical results but the calculation details were not reported.

Comment: Could you give a link to the paper with the model explanation?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Sure! The link is https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.1499124?casa_token=IczQcWrq8HEAAAAA:S4OMMJWHnl62z60dSAQygDnDfPVkK0sTPQbCpQckXLOWpGsz8PBPYIXsyG8zzpaMexF0ISsKWHwv. The title of the paper is "Zero-field electron spin resonance and theoretical studies of light penetration into single crystal and polycrystalline material doped with molecules photoexcitable to the triplet state via intersystem crossing".

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an extended comment, but I am hoping that it will be, at least partially, useful.

```
$Version

13.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit)
```

If you have a look at this equation:

```
   D[Ibar[z, t], z] + η/c D[Ibar[z, t], t] == ((-ρ1[z, t] + ρ2[z, t]) η ℏ ω B 0.5 /c) Ibar[z, t],
```

you see that you have a $z$- and a $t$-derivative for $Ibar$. So, if you try to include that information in the conditions, there's some progress, see below:

```
pde = {
   D[ρ1[z, t], 
     t] == -(η B 0.5/c) Ibar[z, t] ρ1[z, 
       t] + ((η B 0.5/c) Ibar[z, 
          t] + (1 - Φisc)/τF) ρ2[z, t], 
   D[ρ2[z, t], 
     t] == (η B 0.5/c) Ibar[z, t] ρ1[z, 
       t] - ((η B 0.5/c) Ibar[z, t] + 1/τF) ρ2[z, t], 
   D[ρ3[z, t], t] == Φisc/τF ρ2[z, t], 
   D[Ibar[z, t], 
      z] + η/c D[Ibar[z, t], 
       t] == ((-ρ1[z, t] + ρ2[z, 
          t]) η ℏ  ω B 0.5/c) Ibar[z, t],
   ρ1[z, 0] == 10^16,
   ρ2[z, 0] == 0,
   ρ3[z, 0] == 0,
   Ibar[0, t] == 10^16,
   Ibar[z, 0] == 0};
```

and then

```
NDSolveValue[pde, {ρ1[z, t], ρ2[z, t], ρ3[z, t], 
  Ibar[z, t]}, {z, 0, 4 10^-3}, {t, 0, 2 10^-6}, 
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
     "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}]
```

you get the following errors:

> [image: error1]
> [image: error2]

and the output:

> [image: output]

Ok, so I was not inspired enough to find an appropriate value for `Ibar[z, 0]` -sorry- but I tried the use of [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html)

```
pde = {
   D[ρ1[z, t], 
     t] == -(η B 0.5/c) Ibar[z, t] ρ1[z, 
       t] + ((η B 0.5/c) Ibar[z, 
          t] + (1 - Φisc)/τF) ρ2[z, t], 
   D[ρ2[z, t], 
     t] == (η B 0.5/c) Ibar[z, t] ρ1[z, 
       t] - ((η B 0.5/c) Ibar[z, t] + 1/τF) ρ2[z, t], 
   D[ρ3[z, t], t] == Φisc/τF ρ2[z, t], 
   D[Ibar[z, t], 
      z] + η/c D[Ibar[z, t], 
       t] == ((-ρ1[z, t] + ρ2[z, 
          t]) η ℏ  ω B 0.5/c) Ibar[z, t],
   ρ1[z, 0] == 10^16,
   ρ2[z, 0] == 0,
   ρ3[z, 0] == 0,
   Ibar[0, t] == 10^16,
   Ibar[z, 0] == xx};
```

and then

```
family = 
 ParametricNDSolveValue[
  pde, {ρ1[z, t], ρ2[z, t], ρ3[z, t], Ibar[z, t]}, {z, 
   0, 4 10^-3}, {t, 0, 2 10^-6}, xx, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}]
```

returns

[image: paramout]

Comment: Ah, impressive!!! Thanks for your help! I am now going to play with these values and try to find out the appropriate values of rho1 and Ibar.

Comment: @Wuritianoo Glad I was able to help :-) Good luck!!!